# Convert to valid lat/long codes

Tags: google-maps, latitude-longitude

My source gave me the following lat and long codes from Amsterdam. But I can't get them working with Google Maps. Is there some logic behind it, or some kind of algorithm to convert them?

```
5,237,300,539,279,090 | 489,290,714,263,916
```

Should be something like this:

```
52.378268, 4.888859
```

How can one tell where the dots should be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I guess:

- Remove the comma's (it's the thousands separator in the Netherlands)
- Assume 14 decimals

[52.37300539279090, 4.89290714263916](http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=52.37300539279090,+4.89290714263916+&sll=52.379493,4.637718&sspn=0.200142,0.235519&ie=UTF8&t=h&z=16)

Comment: Do they always have 14 decimals? Is that a valid assumption? (just asking)

Comment: I don't know, I just made this up.

Comment: Thanks for your help Sjoerd, in the end I found out that the source kind of messed up the lat/longs. The Excel sheet had some sort of default formatting for those cells.